# Python + Selenium: I can't find an element on my router 'site'

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, automation

I am trying to write a Python script to automate changing my Wi-Fi password from my router site (10.0.0.2). I'm using Selenium and I have been hitting a brick wall because I can't find some elements. Your help will highly be appreciated. I will provide all necessary resources for debugging below:

### I succeeded logging into my router with find element by XPath.

### Locates the submit/login button and clicks it:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="submit"]').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)`
```

### Also, I tried several ways to find the element, but I commented them out temporarily.

```
#Locate Advanced Tab --1
browser.find_element_by_name("Advanced").click()

#Locate Advanced Tab --2
#tt1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@id='topnav1']")
#tt1.click()

[1]#Locates the the advance tab on the page -- 3
#adv = browser.find_element_by_id('topnav1')
#adv.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

---

This is the code for "Advanced" tab in my router:

```
<td id="topnav1" class="topnavoff" width="140"><a       href="javascript:ontopnav('1')">Advanced</a></td>
```

### Edited: Code and error respectively.

```
browser.find_element_by_link_text("Advanced").click()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "celenium.py", line 22, in 
>       browser.find_element_by_link_text("Advanced").click()
>     File "C:\Users\Aesop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 337, in find_element_by_link_text
>       return self.find_element(by=By.LINK_TEXT, value=link_text)
>     File "C:\Users\Aesop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 791, in find_element
>       'value': value})['value']
>     File "C:\Users\Aesop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>     File "C:\Users\Aesop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: Advanced

---

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#topnav1>a").click()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "celenium.py", line 20, in 
>       browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#topnav1>a").click()
>     File "C:\Users\Aesop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 457, in find_element_by_css_selector
>       return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
>     File "C:\Users\Aesop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 791, in find_element
>       'value': value})['value']
>     File "C:\Users\Aesop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>     File "C:\Users\Aesop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: #topnav1>a

---

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("td.topnavoff#topnav1 > a ").click()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "celenium.py", line 22, in 
>       browser.find_element_by_css_selector("td.topnavoff#topnav1 > a ").click()
>     File "C:\Users\Aesop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 457, in find_element_by_css_selector
>       return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
>     File "C:\Users\Aesop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 791, in find_element
>       'value': value})['value']
>     File "C:\Users\Aesop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>     File "C:\Users\Aesop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: td.topnavoff#topnav1 > a

---

### Snippet code from router site:

```
<table id=topnav_container2 cellspacing=0 border=0>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 1px; background-color: white"></td>
          <td id=modnum rowspan=2><img alt="" src="pic/DSL-G225.gif"></td>
          <td style="width: 2px; background-color: white"></td>
          <td id=topnav0 class=topnavon width=140 rowspan=2><a href="javascript:ontopnav('0')" >Setup</a></td>
          <td style="width: 2px; background-color: white"></td>
          <td id=topnav1 class=topnavoff width=140><a href="javascript:ontopnav('1')">Advanced</a></td>
          <td style="width: 2px; background-color: white"></td>
          <td id=topnav2 class=topnavoff width=140><a href="javascript:ontopnav('2')">Maintenance</a></td>
          <td style="width: 2px; background-color: white"></td>
          <td id=topnav3 class=topnavoff width=140><a href="javascript:ontopnav('3')">Status</a></td>
          <td style="width: 2px; background-color: white"></td>
          <td id=topnav4 class=topnavoff width=140><a href="javascript:ontopnav('4')">Help</a></td>
          <td style="width: 2px; background-color: white"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td style="background-color: #404343"></td>
          <td style="background-color: #404343"></td>
          <td style="background-color: #404343"></td>
          <td style="background-color: #404343"></td>
          <td style="background-color: #404343"></td>
          <td style="background-color: #404343"></td>
          <td style="background-color: #404343"></td>
          <td style="background-color: #404343"></td>
          <td style="background-color: #404343"></td>
          <td style="background-color: #404343"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: Do you have frames on your page?

Comment: @Ratmir Yes, sir.

Comment: @Originull when you say you have `frames`, did you switch to the exact `frame`? Post more of `outerHTML` containing the `<frame>` tag and your code trial to switch frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the `link` with text as **`Advanced`** you can use any of the following line of code :

- **`css_selector`** :

  ```
  browser.find_element_by_css_selector("table#topnav_container2 tr td.topnavoff#topnav1 > a").click()
  ```
- **`xpath`** :

  ```
  browser.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='topnav_container2']//tr//td[@class='topnavoff' and @id='topnav1']/[contains(.,'Advanced')]").click()
  ```

> **Note** : The `link` with text as **`Advanced`** is within an `<a>` tag. Hence you must try to invoke the powerful **click()** method instead of **`send_keys(Keys.RETURN)`** or **`send_keys(Keys.ENTER)`** as follows :

```
browser.find_element_by_link_text("Advanced").click()
```

Comment: Thank you very much.... although I still have this bug.

I don't think _Advanced_ is a link per se. Which is why I think It's so difficult to locate it. :( 

I've tried your methods Ratmir and DebanjanB, and thank you once again, but I'm still failing.

Comment: @Originull Updated my Answer. Let me know the status. See the `<a>` tag have `href` attribute defined with value set to `javascript:ontopnav('1')`. So it is definitely a link. **still failing** doesn't throws any light on what is happening. Update the question with your latest code trials and error stack trace so the SO volunteers can help you out.

Comment: `xpath` and `css` looks fine as per the HTML. Can you show more of the `outerHTML`. Either there are multiple elements with same `xpath`/`css` or element is within a `frame`

Comment: I just pasted a snippet code. Would posting the whole page source code be better?

Comment: Try with the updated `xpath` and `css` and let me know the status.

Comment: I think I know what the problem was. 

    _browser.find_element_by_css_selector("table#topnav_container2 tr td.topnavoff#topnav1 > a").click()_

This code worked after I added the Time module. Haha... I think It's because I never included sleep. 

This is the final code:

    _sleep(5)
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("table#topnav_container2 tr td.topnavoff#topnav1 > a").click()_

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time and help!

Comment: I have same problem, I start to think if this could be due to a security issue on routers. Elements are perfectly found using browser dev tools, example: $x("//input[@name='txtPassword']"), but not through selenium =(